# Xamarin Forms - Settings bindings as colours depending on existence in a list

Tags: mvvm, binding, xamarin.forms

The scenario is as follows:

```
public enum DayOfWeek
{
    All = 0,
    Monday = 1,
    Tuesday = 2, 
    Wednesday = 3,
    Thursday = 4,
    Friday = 5,
    Saturday = 6,
    Sunday = 7
}

public class Class2{
    public List<DayOfWeek> DaysOfWeek
}

public class Class1{
    public List<Class2> aList{get; set;}
}
```

I have Class1 in my ViewModel which is linked to the View via BindingContext.

I want to show in a list List which I am currently doing.

In the ListView, I define a ViewCell (inside  ) like:

```
<Grid Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center" RowSpacing="1" ColumnSpacing="2">
     <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
          <ColumnDefinition Width="17"/>
          <ColumnDefinition Width="17"/>
          <ColumnDefinition Width="17"/>
          <ColumnDefinition Width="17"/> 
          <ColumnDefinition Width="17"/>                               
          <ColumnDefinition Width="17"/>
          <ColumnDefinition Width="17"/>
     </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
     <Grid.RowDefinitions>
          <RowDefinition Height="17"/>
          <RowDefinition Height="17"/>
     </Grid.RowDefinitions>

     <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Text="M" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center"/> 
     <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Text="T" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center"/>
     <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" Text="W" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center"/>
     <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="3" Text="T" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center"/>
     <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="4" Text="F" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center"/>
     <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="5" Text="S" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center"/>
     <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="6" Text="S" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center"/>

     <BoxView Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center"/> 
     <BoxView Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center"/>
     <BoxView Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center"/>
     <BoxView Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="3" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center"/>
     <BoxView Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="4" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center"/>
     <BoxView Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="5" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center"/>
     <BoxView Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="6" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center"/>
</Grid>
```

Basically I am planning to show DaysOfWeek in boxes and color them in red or green depending if a day is in DaysOfWeek.

I think that to set the color I need to use a Converter that checks the days that are contained in the list (DaysOfWeek) and return green if so, red otherwise. Is this correct?

How should I set the bindings? How to point to and element of a list inside a list?

Currently I am having quite enough problems to set the bindings other properties of Class 2 or Class1 using MVVM.

Any idea?

Comment: You need to use a ListView and add there the binding to your aList of your viewmodel and define in the view the binding context to your viewmodel too, also now looking again you define your aList like a list of Class2 that contains a list, this is confusing, why you doing that?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Do I need a ListView? Cannot I use those BoxViews?  It is the way I thought about it. I have a list of Movies and each Movie has a list of days to be shown. Any advise to do it better?